# Azure SQL Automation stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I am migrating on premises SQL server database to Azure PaaS SQL database using Data Migration Tool. I am not using Data Migration Service Instance mechanism to migrate the database as it would require VPN on the corporate network and I do not see any benefit doing that way in my case.
There is one error which I am stuck on and a bit confused. When migrating a stored procedure which use automation stored procedures, I get the following error:
[image]

When I run Alter procedure script directly on Azure SQL database , I get this error;
**Reference to database and/or server name in 'MASTER..sp_OACreate' is not supported in this version of SQL Server**.A few answers to similar question on stackoverflow suggest that Azure SQL does not support automation stored procedures but the Microsoft link has a green tick against Azure SQL which suggest it does; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/ole-automation-sample-script?view=sql-server-2017.
A snippet of the sp is:

[image]

Is it true that automation stored procedures are not supported in Azure SQL and if thats hte case then what is hte workaround apart from rewriting the sp?

Comment: if you check this documentation, you can see that `sp_OACreate` does not exist in Azure SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Don't know what this is for but you will have to do some rewrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Azure prevents you from calling server resources. sp_OACreate attempts to create a reference to an OLE object on the server; that's simply not allowed on Azure SQL Database. So you will need to redesign your solution to move this type of logic in a middle-tier of some kind, such as a [Web Role](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/03/31/applying-a-web-and-worker-roles-pattern-to-the-azure-app-service/) in Windows Azure.